# Changing a data attribute on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I was wondering how I could change a data attribute on click. What I would like to do is to increment the value by 25. So I have a Progress bar and a button. Right now the progress bar has a value of 25. When I click the button I would like it to increment to 50, 75, 100

Here is the code:

```js
let button = document.getElementById("btn");
let bar = document.getElementById("progress-bar");

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  console.log("you clicked the btn");
});
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 3em;
}

progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: orange !important;
}

button {
  margin-top: 2em;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: .5em 2em;
}
button:hover {
  background: #1a1a1a;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h2>Quiz Progress</h2>
  <progress max='100' value='25'></progress>
  <button id='btn'>Next</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `**value**` property of [progress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress) element. you didn't had id assigned to progress element but you were trying to access it.

```js
let button = document.getElementById("btn");
let bar = document.getElementById("progress-bar");

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  //console.log("you clicked the btn");
  if(bar.value>=100)
  {
    bar.value=100;
  }
  else
  {
    bar.value+=25;
  }
  
});
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 3em;
}

progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: orange !important;
}

button {
  margin-top: 2em;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: .5em 2em;
}
button:hover {
  background: #1a1a1a;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h2>Quiz Progress</h2>
  <progress id="progress-bar" max='100' value='25'></progress>
  <button id='btn'>Next</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, this helped me out a lot!